# Mysql select order by date desc then group by column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi i want to select from a table order by date desc than gruoup by smth. At first phpmyadmin give an error (sql_mode=only_full_group_by) and i fix it by removing that flag from my.cnf and i don't know if this fix is good for long term, i read somewhere that with this fix you can get unwanted results. i've tried `**select * from ( select * from log order by date desc) tmp group by imei**` but the results are from the oldest date not from the newest date, it gives me the imei from the first id not from the last.

Comment: There is no difference in the results between `select * from ( select * from log order by date desc) tmp group by imei` and `select * from ( select * from log order by date) tmp group by imei`

Comment: I've tried now `select * from ( select * from log order by date desc limit 100) tmp group by imei` and it's working but i don't want to limit the results

Answer (score 0):

For the grouping result, it doesn't matter if you've ordered the input. If I interpret your question correctly, you want to get the latest log entry for each imei. You would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT l1.*
  FROM logs as l1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN logs as l2
  ON l1.imei = l2.imei
    AND l1.date < l2.date
  WHERE l2.date IS NULL
```

where you are essentially asking for each log entry (l1) for which no log entry (l2) exists with the same imei, but a greater date.

If you only want to know when the last log entry for each imei was, this will be enough:

```
SELECT imei, MAX(date)
  FROM log
  GROUP BY imei
```

Comment: i've tried your first command but it takes too long and i don't recive a result, it just stays in loading. I want to do exactly wat you did whith the 2-nd command but i want to sellect all the columns not just imei and date

Comment: i've have deleted where l2.date is null but it gives me all data from the table not unique datas by imei

Comment: If the result takes to long, you should add indexes on the imei and date columns.

When you delete the "WHERE l2.date IS NULL" part, you ask for all the entries and that's what you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM log WHERE id in ( SELECT max(id) FROM log group by imei)